# How to validate fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django. I was a .NET developer. I've created a form for new users' registration, but my problem is that I need some validation controls to validate my fields.
I could not find any resources or examples.
Any help, please?

My newuser.html is in the below:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Name </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Username </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Password </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Confirm password </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword">
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>email </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="email">
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" colspan=2>
            </td>
        </tr>    
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: With Django forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/

Comment: Because you come from .NET do you know nothing about [DRY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) :) Take a look to forms topic posted by Willem.

Comment: Apart from what william said do check this too for defining your custom validations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/

Answer (score 0):

Django is server-side. You can accept any old rubbish back from the client, because you can be sure that some hacker somewhere  will be trying "Little Bobby Tables" and suchlike on you. (XKCD reference).

So regardless of whatever you do client-side, Django forms protect you. If the stuff from the client passes `form.is_valid()`, proceed. If not, redisplay the form with errors. The CBV `FormView` will do all this for you.

As for whatever client-side validation you want, Django doesn't provide it. If you use Bootstrap, you'll get a certain amount automagically.

Comment: I will give you an example if I want to check the email format in the email field I need an email validator to check it, or if I need to check if all mandatory fields are filled or not.

Comment: Django will do that server-side. It's a form with an EmailField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield declared as required. You can add custom validation, for example should you wish to restrict valid domains. Using Bootstrap client-side, it won't allow submission with a blank field because it's required. If you want client-side parsing you need to supply your own JavaScript validation code. I don't see any point in this because one can never trust what is POSTed from the internet. The server MUST validate it.